# Install Jenkins on RedHat to specific location

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, redhat, yum

I need to install Jenkins on RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 64 to a specific location /opt/user/buildserver. I am pretty sure that when I do it with yum as described in http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/ it will be installed somewhere else. Has anybody had similar problem and sorted it out somehow?

Comment: Why do you need it installed into that location specifically? What is that going to do for you? What is your goal with doing that?

Comment: The machine hosts many other build servers and tools. Just for clear distinction which Jenkins belongs to me and is under my supervision.

Comment: Then you get to not use an rpm for it. That being said those rpm's are effectively just a .`war` file, a service file and some directories. So manually extracting it and installing the file where you want it isn't hard (but won't register it with `rpm` obviously).